# Trouble with responsive header

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with trying to make the header logo and the links announce my report and send me alerts as shown on this [page](http://www.reportalert.info/index-test.php) re size into what is shown in this image [here](http://www.reportalert.info/images/03mobileview-alerts320.jpg).

I've tried adjusting the margin and padding of the links when the browser re sizes with media query but I can't seem to get the links to stay on the same line and I also cant seem to get the first link announce my report to float to left so that it goes right to edge once it re sizes. Any suggestions on how I can get it to re size down to that for mobile layout?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="logo" style="float:left"> <a href="http://www.reportalert.info/">
       <img src="images/nra/ra-logo.png" />
        </a> </div>
      <div id="utils-red" align="right"> <a class="announce_red" href="/announce">announce my report</a> <a class="sendalerts_red" href="/signup">send me alerts</a> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#utils-red
{
float:right;
margin:55px 0 0 0;
color:#fff;
font-family: 'RBNo21a-BlackDEMO';
font-size:23px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
height:37px;
font-variant:small-caps;
}

a.announce_red, a.sendalerts_red
{
clear:both;
background:url(/images/nra/ra-red-action.png) left repeat-x;
background-position: 0 -35px;
padding:5px 20px;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 0 0 20px;
outline:none;
}
a.announce_red:hover, a.sendalerts_red:hover
{
background-position:0 0;
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px 20px;
outline:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like this to your styles:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #utils-red {float: none;}
    a.announce_red, a.sendalerts_red {margin: 0 20px 0 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want links on the same line, you need to float also your tag `<a>`.

Try:

```
.announce_red, .sendalerts_red {
   float: left;
}
```

P.S:
You need to remove `clear:both;`

Answer (score 0):

your css can be changed as follows

```
#utils-red
{
margin:55px 0 0 0;
color:#fff;
font-family: 'RBNo21a-BlackDEMO';
font-size:10px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-align:center;
font-variant:small-caps;
}

a.announce_red, a.sendalerts_red
{
float:left;
background:url(/images/nra/ra-red-action.png) left repeat-x;
background-position: 0 -35px;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
margin-left:20px;
}

a.announce_red:hover, a.sendalerts_red:hover
{
background-position:0 0;
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;
}
```

:)